# How can I put async pipe into my custom pipe

Tags: angular, typescript

I want to create a pipe in angular which uses the observable method because of that I should return observable when I wanna use this pipe I have to put the `async` pipe and my pipe together

Is there any way to put async pipe inside of my pipe?

```
@Pipe({
  name: 'toEnum'
})
export class ToEnumPipe implements PipeTransform {
  constructor(private translate: TranslateService) {}

    transform(value: number, model: EnumModel[]): Observable<string> {
    const txt = model.filter(x => x.value === value).map(x => x.text)[0];
    return this.translate.get(txt);
  }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

In case this isn't clear for everyone, it's as easy as...

```
<div *ngFor="let product of (products$ | async | searchFilter: (query$ | async) )">
```

Notice the brackets (query$ | async) already in an async pipe operation.